# Token arrives as "undefined" CORS, Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, google-chrome, spring-security, jwt, cors

In my client, the token arrives as "undefined," but when I enable the Moesif CORS Chrome extension, the token arrives correctly.

I have made many changes to the code, but I still haven't found a solution.

I tried enabling global CORS, but it didn't work either. In the Chrome tools, under the Network tab, the `Authorization` header shows the token. However, in my client, it still appears as "undefined." Only when using the Moesif CORS Chrome extension do I receive the token correctly.

I also tried making changes in the client, but it didn't work.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
//import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
//import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter;
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authManager) throws Exception {
        
        JWTAuthenticationFilter  jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter();
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        jwtAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
        
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/datatable").authenticated() 
                    .anyRequest().permitAll() 
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5173"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
    
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception {
        return http
                .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                    .and()
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    //@Bean
    //public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        //return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
           // @Override
           // public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
               // registry.addMapping("/**")
                        //.allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
                        //.allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS") 
                        //.allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Content-Type") 
                        //.allowCredentials(true);
                
           // }
        //};
    //}
    
    //public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("pass:" + new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("******"));
    //}
}
```

[Newtwork-Header-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEvUe.png)

client Vue.js and axios

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formulario: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      token: '' 
    };
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', this.formulario)
        .then(response => {
          this.token = response.headers['authorization']; 
          localStorage.setItem('token', this.token); 

          console.log(response.headers['authorization']);
          console.log('Token recibido:', this.token); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error iniciando sesión', error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Show your network tab in your browser. Show your request and response with headers. Show your client code. What client framework do you use?

Comment: What is `jwtAuthorizationFilter` and why is it exposed as a bean?

Comment: I updated the post with the screenshot of the Google Developer Tools and the client code. I'm using Vue.js and Axios.

Comment: The screenshot only shows the repsonse headers, I need to see the request headers, too. That is the value of `origin` header?